# '\n\t\r' == 0 is true?

Tags: javascript

Today when I was doing some experiments with `==`, I accidentally found out that `"\n\t\r" == 0`. How on earth does `"\n\t\r"` equal to `0`, or `false`?

What I did is:

```
var txt = "\n";  //new line
txt == 0;        //it gives me true
```

And that really annoy me. So I did more:

```
var txt = "\r";  //"return"
txt == 0;        //true

var txt = "\t";  //"tab"
txt == 0;        //true
```

It does not make sense, at all. How's that happen? And more crazy is this:

```
//Checking for variable declared or not

var txt ="\n\t\r";
if(txt!=false){
    console.log("Variable is declared.");
}else{
    console.log("Variable is not declared.");
}
```

What it gives me is `Variable is not declared.`

How is it equal to `0`, or `false`???

Comment: [Welcome to Javascript](http://wiki.theory.org/YourLanguageSucks#JavaScript_sucks_because:).

Comment: I would say "because the string is empty"

Comment: @Mehrdad - LOL, it said in JavaScript `0.1 + 0.2 --> 0.30000000...4` And I don't believe it and I tried and I got the same thing. Never notice it before!

Comment: @Derek: lol, like I said... welcome to Javascript. :P (Though to be honest, that particular problem is the least worrisome, since it's the same issue in many other languages...)

Comment: @Derek: This is some behavior you will see in every language using IEEE floating point numbers (which is about every language out there)

Comment: Also this: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Comment: @Mehrdad: Just read through most of the wiki page. And I have to say that more than half of it is either plain wrong, describes a deliberate design aspect, is easily avoidable by using best practices, or was an issue 5 years ago (except the PHP stuff, that language just sucks :). But generally, I'm not impressed...

Comment: They are all expected results. Section 11.9.3 explains them all. Standard ECMA-262: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf

Comment: @RayCheng: Wouldn't it be odd if the specification for a language would disagree with its implementation? Nevertheless, some concepts like weak typing (JS, PHP) can be unexpected for people used to strongly typed languages (C, Java, Ruby).

Comment: @HolgerJust: Yeah I agree, I wasn't really endorsing it either. I just found it to be a nice link w.r.t. the question.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This behaviour might be surprising but can be explained by having a look at the [specification](http://es5.github.com/).

We have to look at the what happens when a comparison with the [*equals* operator](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.1) is performed. The exact algorithm is defined in [section 11.9.3](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3).

I built a simple tool to demonstrate which algorithm steps are executed: https://felix-kling.de/js-loose-comparison/

---

#### `string == integer`

The step we have to look at is #5:

> 5. If `Type(x)` is String and `Type(y)` is Number,
> return the result of the comparison `ToNumber(x) == y`.

That means the string `"\n"` (`"\r"`, `"\t"`) is converted to a number first and then compared against `0`.

How is a string converted to a number? This is explained in [section 9.3.1](http://es5.github.com/#x9.3.1). In short, we have:

> The MV (mathematical value) of `StringNumericLiteral ::: StrWhiteSpace` is `0`.

where `StrWhiteSpace` is defined as

```
StrWhiteSpace :::
    StrWhiteSpaceChar StrWhiteSpace_opt

StrWhiteSpaceChar :::
    WhiteSpace
    LineTerminator
```

This just means that the numerical value of strings containing white space characters and/or a line terminator is `0`.
Which characters are considered as white space characters is defined in [section 7.3](http://es5.github.com/#x7.2).

---

#### `string == boolean`

The step we have to look at is #7:

> 7. If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison `x == ToNumber(y)`.

How booleans are converted to numbers is pretty simple: `true` becomes `1` and `false` becomes `0`.

Afterwards we are comparing a string against a number, which is explained above.

---

As others have mentioned, strict comparison (`===`) can be used to avoid this "problem". Actually you should only be using the normal comparison if you know what you are doing and want this behaviour.

Answer (score 12):

Because JavaScript is a loosely typed language, it attempts to type cast your 1st side of the comparison to the other so that they would match each other.

Any string which does not contain a number, becomes 0 when compared to an integer, and becomes true (Except in certain situations), when compared to a Boolean.

**[Light reading material.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)**

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature!

Comment: Your answer is a bit confusing - if a string is compared to a string it sure remains a string (maybe you wanted to say "number" there?).

Comment: Regarding *"Any string which does not contain a number, becomes 0 when compared to an integer"*, how do you explain `"abc" == 0 // false` then?

Comment: Also the second part of the statement is not correct: *"and becomes true (if not an empty string), when compared to a Boolean"*. `"0" == false` yields `true`. According to your explanation, `"0"` would be converted to `true`, so it should yield `false`. In fact, both operands are converted to numbers first and are then compared. Note that there is a difference between *comparing* a string to a boolean and *evaluating* a string *as* boolean.

Comment: Indeed @FelixKling, should probably mention that `"string"==0` basically gets interpreted as `Number("string")==0`. And for some reason whitespace strings get cast to 0, and strings with characters get cast to `NaN`.

Answer (score 4):

`txt` is not a `Boolean`, so it will never be `false`. It can be `undefined` though.

```
var txt ="\n\t\r";
if(txt !== undefined) { //or just: if (txt)
    console.log("Variable is declared.");
} else {
    console.log("Variable is not declared.");
}
//=> will log: 'Variable is declared.'
```

By the way, a *declared* variable may be `undefined` (e.g. `var txt;`).

If you do a stricter comparison (without type coercion, using `===`), you'll see that

```
var txt = '\n'; txt === 0; //=> false
var txt = '\r'; txt === 0; //=> false
var txt = '\t'; txt === 0; //=> false
```

[See also](http://javascript.crockford.com/style2.html)

Comment: `!==` disables the type conversion, so even `txt !== false` would give you `true` on that.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `"\n\t\r"` just as `" "` are treated as empty strings.
If you use `==` it will return `true` but if you use `===` it will return `false`.

If you want to test for existence you should use something like

```
if(typeof strName !== 'undefined') {
    /*do something with strName*/
} else {
    /*do something without it*/
}
```

Comment: I don't think these quotes are acceptable by JavaScript as string delimiters.

Comment: You're wrong about that - only "" is an empty string, " " is not. Try `if (" ") alert("hi");` to see it in action.

Comment: `> " " == 0` returns
`true `

using node.js

Comment: That's right, because " " is a string - if you compare that to a number (what 0 is), it will be converted to a number as well before comparing the value - hence the actual comparison will be "0 === 0" and that sure is true.

Comment: it's not because it's a string, because if you test for `"test" == 0` it will return `false`. " " is an empty string whereas "test" is not.

Comment: Ok, you're right - empty strings convert to 0 while "test" will convert to NaN.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use the `== operator` and try to compare a string to a number, the string will first be converted to a number. Thus: `alert("\n\r"==0) becomes: alert(Number("\n\r")==0)`
The Number constructure is kind of interesting. It will first strip whitespace then decide if the number is a not a number or not. If `NaN`, then the result is "`NaN`". If the string is empty, then the result is 0.

```
alert(Number()) alerts 0
alert(Number("")) alerts 0
alert(Number(" \n \r \n \t")) alerts 0
alert(Number("blah")) alerts NaN
alert(Number("0xFF")) alerts 255
alert(Number("1E6")) alerts 1000000
```

To check if the result is NaN use isNaN()

```
Thus: alert(isNaN("blah")) alerts true
Thus: alert(isNaN("")) alerts false
Thus: alert(isNaN("\n")) alerts false
Thus: alert(isNaN(" ")) alerts false
```

however do note that NaN will never equal NaN:

```
var nan=Number("geh");alert(nan==nan);  alerts false
```

**Update:**

if you want to check if both sides are NaN, then you'd convert both to boolean values first like so:

```
var nan=Number("geh");alert(!!nan==!!nan); alerts true
```

**or better yet**

```
var nan=Number("geh");
alert(isNaN(nan)&& isNaN(nan));
```