# Why (!a) and (a == false) are not equal?

Tags: javascript

Talk is cheap, I will show my code.

```
    var a; // a = undefined
    if(a == false){ // As I typed == not ===, a needs to be translated to boolean (undefined == false) but it doesn't
      return false;
    } 
    else {
      return true;
    }
   // true
```

This returns true but I was sure that it would return false because undefined is the same as false when I'm using double equal.

Things came strange when I tried to use

```
if(!a){..} else {..};
// false
```

Here I got my false but till this moment I thought (!a) and (a == false) are absolutely equals.

Comment: only `undefined == null` is `true` not `undefined == false`.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir: What does this have to do with `null`?

Comment: @FelixKling He's probably mixing them up (thinking that all falsy values are equal when using `==` but only `null` and `undefined` do).

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

Comment: *"because undefined is the same as false when I'm using double equal."* - This is incorrect. `undefined == false` evaluates to `false`.

Comment: `!a` converts `a`
 to a boolean, while the second one is a direct comparison with a boolean. besides, `!a` is like "as long as it's not **falsey**", while `a == false` explicitly compares `a` to a boolean, which is different in javascript.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The short answer:

`!a` **converts** a value to a Boolean.
`a == false` **compares** a value to a Boolean.

These are two different operations.

---

`!a` is equivalent to `Boolean(a) ? false : true`. `Boolean(a)` returns `false` if `a` is

- `undefined`
- `null`
- `0`
- `''`
- `NaN`
- `false`

In every other case it returns `true`.

What happens in `a == false` is a [bit more evolved](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison), but not that complicated. The most important thing that happens is that `false` is converted to a number, so you are actually comparing `a == 0`. But `undefined` is treated in a special way in the comparison algorithm. It's not converted to any other type, so the algorithm simply returns `false`.

[I wrote the following interactive tool](http://felix-kling.de/jsbasics/#/17) for a JavaScript course which shows you which steps of the algorithm are performed when comparing two values:

[image]

---

Similar questions:

- [In JavaScript, why is "0" equal to false, but when tested by 'if' it is not false by itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7615214/218196)
- [Why does ('0' ? 'a' : 'b') behave different than ('0' == true ? 'a' : 'b')](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7496727/218196)
- [JavaScript: What is the difference between `if (!x)` and `if (x == null)`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5791158/218196)
- [Why "" == "0" is false in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21889320/218196)

Answer (score 2):

The only correct answer is "that's the way it is". The source of your confusion is a feature of JavaScript called [**type coercion**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) and different types of equality comprisons (`==`, `===` in JavaScript).

There's an interesting table which tells you which comparisons will result to `true` on [JavaScript Equality Table](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/).

The only two values which will give `true` when `==`-compared with `null` are `null` and `undefined`.

In other words, `x == null` will be `true` if and only if `x` is `null` or `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

You had a false assumption. `x == false` does not coerect `x` to `boolean`. In fact, `==` has it's [own equality table](http://algassert.com/visualization/2014/03/27/Better-JS-Equality-Table.html).

If you don't believe random blogposts, here is the [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison):

> 7.2.12 Abstract Equality Comparison
>
> The comparison x == y, where x and y are values, produces true or
>   false. Such a comparison is performed as follows:
>
> 1. ReturnIfAbrupt(x).
> 2. ReturnIfAbrupt(y).
> 3. If Type(x) is the same as Type(y), then Return the result of performing Strict Equality Comparison x === y.
> 4. If x is null and y is undefined, return true.
> 5. If x is undefined and y is null, return true.
> 6. If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).
> 7. If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.
> 8. If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.
> 9. If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).
> 10. If Type(x) is either String, Number, or Symbol and Type(y) is Object, then return the result of the comparison x == ToPrimitive(y).
> 11. If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String, Number, or Symbol, then return the result of the comparison ToPrimitive(x) == y.
> 12. Return false.

So for `undefined == false`: first we hit `#9`, and then `#12`, which evaluates to false.

Answer (score 1):

> (!a) and (a == false) are absolutely equals.

you use two different operators and assume they are **absolutely** equals - never do this, there is a reason 2 different operators exists instead of 1.

Now, think of `NaN` (as one example, others may apply). By definition `NaN` is a **falsy** value but not `false` value, so:

```
if(!NaN) {} // this will execute
if(NaN == false) {} // this will not execute
```

Why do you think this happens?

Because `==` operator does type coercion per type/value, thus `NaN` doesn't coerce to `false`, while others, like `0` may, but both will be considered **falsy** and converted to `true` using `!`

Summed:

- operator `!` uses a defined set of **falsy** values (`false`,`0`, `''` or `""` (empty string), `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`) all else is **truthy**
- operator `==` uses per type conversions not regarding if the original value is considered **falsy**, so after being converted, it may well be **truthy**

Comment: Thanks.
If I understand right, (a == true) and (a) are different operators too, aren't they?

Comment: do you write them the same? asking if "!" is different than "==" is like asking if "==" is different than "===" is like asking if "1" is different than "2"... on the rare occasions when two things are the same, people will tell you, every other assumption is just common sense: **you write it different** means **it is different**